# Can I destructure a variable where property name defined by a variable itself?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

For example I have in `localStorage` object properties `Meteor.userId` and `Meteor.loginToken`. I can destructure them as following:

```
const {
      'Meteor.userId': userId,
      'Meteor.loginToken': loginToken,
    } = localStorage;
```

But can I define `Meteor.userId` and `Meteor.loginToken` as a variables? For example:

```
const METEOR_USER_ID = 'Meteor.userId';
const METEOR_LOGIN_TOKEN = 'Meteor.loginToken';
```

Tried to use the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
const {
      METEOR_USER_ID: userId,
      METEOR_LOGIN_TOKEN: loginToken,
    } = localStorage;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to take the key of the variable.

```
const {
    [METEOR_USER_ID]: userId,
    [METEOR_LOGIN_TOKEN]: loginToken,
} = localStorage;
```

Comment: @Quentin, you miss the right key, starting with `'Meteor`. this is not the name of the object.

Comment: Ah. I had the two sides of the renaming feature backwards in my head.